# About some quotient of finitely generated group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group. Assume there exists $N$ an abelian normal subgroup of $G$, such that $G/N=H$ with $H$ a finite group of order not divisible by a fixed prime number $p$. In particular $N$ is finitely generated and abelian so $N=Z \times F$ with $Z$ finite and $F$ free and abelian.

My questions are:

1. Can I say that $Z$ has order prime to $p$?
2. Is $G/F$ finite with order prime to $p$?
3. Is it true that $G$ not contain elements of order $p$?

I am a freshman in group theory and I have a bit of problem to solve this questions.

Comment: Let G be the cyclic group of order 6 and N the subgroup of order 2.  Then H is cyclic of order 3.  #H is prime to 2.

Comment: From what you have written $Z$ could be any finite abelian group, so the answer to 1 in no, and similarly for 3. Have you left out some assumption? In 2, there is no reason why $F$ should be a normal subgroup of $G$.